# Swift - how to mimic iOS's Files app expandable navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I'm working on iOS application in Swift and I'm showing a table views in Navigation Controller with a Navigation bar.
I'd like to implemented the same "Toolbar experience" as the **Files app** does. (see attached image) in order to present additional options/buttons without cluttering the screen (for UX purposes mostly).

I could not find anything related, expect for workaround with toolbar on top, but it does not work as part of the navigation bar, meaning that after navigation that toolbar is no following the navigation bar but instead stays on the previous controller.

**The ideal behavior is:**

- to expand when scrolling down (requires table view to be scrolled to top) and to collapse when scrolling down.
- to keep the toolbar attached to the navigation bar on navigation (push & pop)

In the screenshot, the toolbar is showing additional options (under the search bar). I'd very much like to do the same.[image: screenshot of expanded toolbar under navigation bar]